# mysql - explain query with real table names

Tags: mysql, explain

I'm using this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM DB1.TABLE1 AS T1, DB2.TABLE2 AS T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
```

In result, the "table" column which I need to gather tables used in this query, will return the aliases used in query (T1, T2) instead of their real names (TABLE1, TABLE2).

Is there a way to make this query to return the real table names?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer is: no, there is no way...

As pointed out by CodeBird, there is a bug report open on the MySQL bug tracker:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24693

Depsite the fact that the MySQL documentation clearly states "The name of the table to which the row of output refers", all outputs from EXPLAIN are plagued by this problem. Even the new FORMAT=JSON option...

Answer (score -1):

Just use the real table names as ALIAS.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM DB1.TABLE1, DB2.TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
```

Comment: No! I can't change the query! there are lots of queries that I should explain, I can't manually remove the aliases!

Comment: Then you must live with the aliases in EXPLAIN. There is no way to change the output of EXPLAIN this way.

Comment: So, is there any other ways to return all tables used in a query?

Comment: No, there is none. You have `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`. That is all you can count on.

Comment: @michaelropy Here's a useful link if you prefer getting your hands dirty with open source code: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24693

Comment: Just wrote my own RegEx, and it works...thanks everyone